# Filter function on where clause on Azure mobile services Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use a filter function on a [table object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554210.aspx) in the where clause described in the link before, but I can't find any reference about how to write it.

```
     exports.post = function(request, response) {
       var currentdate = (new Date()).getTime();
       takenOffersTable.where(function(request,currentdate){
       return (this.user_id ==  request.user.userId && this.offer_id == request.body.offer_id && this.__updatedAt < currentdate)
       }).read({ success: function(result) { ...
```

but in this way, I get `Error: Expected value(s) for parameter(s) request,currentdate`

and if I write it this way:

```
   exports.post = function() {
       var currentdate = (new Date()).getTime();
       takenOffersTable.where(function(request,currentdate){
       return (this.user_id ==  request.user.userId && this.offer_id == request.body.offer_id && this.__updatedAt < currentdate)
       }).read({ success: function(result) { ...
```

I get `ReferenceError: request is not defined`

How can I give the request and currentdate parameters to the filter function, or how do I write this? 
[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj613353) didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `where(function)` of [table object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554210.aspx), we should add the value of the parameter following the `function(){}` construct in the `where` closure.

Generate as the format like:

```
var variable1,variable2;
...
tableObject.where(function(parameter1,parameter2,...){},variable1,variable2,...)
...
```

And it seems that it will raise the `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` issue if directly set `request` object in the `where` function.

So according your code, you can try to modify it as the following code snippet:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
       var currentdate = (new Date()).getTime();
       takenOffersTable.where(function(user,body,currentdate){
       return (this.user_id ==  user.userId && this.offer_id == body.offer_id && this.__updatedAt < currentdate)
       },request.user,request.body,currentdate).read({ success: function(result) { ...
```

Comment: can I pass some function as argument ?